# Why is FTP file transfer from Android Phone Slow?

Tags: android, ftp

To transfer files from my Android phone to Ubuntu, I use an app that creates a FTP server on the phone.

Copying files to Ubuntu 12.04 (same with 12.10) I get up to 260 KB/s.
Copying files to Windows 7 I get up to 1050 KB/s.

I am currently on a fresh install of 12.10 with barely anything installed with the same results. I have tested with both a Galaxy S3 and HTC Desire HD with identical results. I have tested about 5 apps with the same results.

Why is it slow on Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe it is limited by the WIFI speed on the Android Phone.

Comment: If you are trying to transfer files between android phone and Ubuntu then you can try this method [File transfer through USB tethering](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/237117/350426)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `anon_max_rate` to `0` (i.e. unlimited) - https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html